# Extract rows from 2D array within a model

Tags: c#, linq

I am working in C#. I have a class model:

```
public class CustomerViewModel
{
    public string Name;
    public string[][] values;
    public bool[] flag;
}
```

I wish to extract values[x][0] from all rows of values where flag==false, using LINQ

Comment: "flag" is an array. What's the actual condition on that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this should do it:

```
var result = custVm.flag.Select((f, i) => new { f, val = custVm.values[i][0] })
                        .Where(i => !i.f)
                        .Select(i => i.val);
```

For every entry in the flag array, you're mapping the value from the first column of the values array to a new anonyomous object, containing the flag and the value.

You're then filtering this list of anonymous objects by flag == false.

Then you're selecting just the 'value' parts of the anonymous objects.

Comment: I'm still fuzzy on lambda expressions with multiple variables (or whatever you call the declarations before the `=>`). That, and `.Aggregate()` completely elude me.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var model = new CustomerViewModel()
    {
        flag = new bool[] { false, true, false },
        Name = "a",
        values = new string[][] { 
            new string[] { "a", "b" },
            new string[] { "c", "d" },
            new string[] { "e", "f" }
        }
    };

    var result = model.values
        .Where((v, i) => !model.flag[i])
        .Select(v => v[0]).ToList();
}
```

which returns `a` and `e`.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help... Fortunately Learned a new concept in LINQ after struggling for hours.